# SignalR Connection Limitation for .NET Client

Tags: signalr

I made an experimental solution which includes WebMvc (SignalR Client) -> (SignalR Hub) WebApi.

Each time new user connects to WebMvc web site then it creates new Hub connection to WebApi. It means that if 10K users connect to web site then WebMvc will create 10K connections to SignalR Hub.

Are there any connection limitations for WebMvc application?

Answer (score 5):

The maximum number of concurrent connections depends on your settings.
For SignalR, the limitation depends on your IIS Configuration for:

- Max concurrent requests per application

  > Increasing the number of concurrent IIS requests will increase server
  >   resources available for serving requests. The default value is 5000;
- ApplicationPool QueueLength

  > This is the maximum number of requests that Http.sys queues for the
  >   application pool. When the queue is full, new requests receive a 503
  >   “Service Unavailable” response. The default value is 1000;

[SignalR Performance](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#tuning)
[Optimizing IIS Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance)