# SignalR Max Connections

Tags: azure-web-app-service, signalr-hub, signalr.client

On a **Azure WebApp** Service, with **selfhosted SignalR Hub** (inside IIS) does someone know the maximum number of concurrent connections that the Hub can broadcast to without problems? Can someone suggest any trick to avoid disconnection of the clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SignalR, the limitation depends on your IIS Configuration.

Thanks for [Florin Secal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571002/signalr-connection-limitation-for-net-client) to explains the maximum number of connections.

> Can someone suggest any trick to avoid disconnection of the clients?

I think we don't need any way to avoid this, we only need to use Reconnections reasonably.